# Let draggable do its work only if mouse cursor on a draggable element is default cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have used jQueryUI's draggable method on a div.

```
var data = '<div> <p> Draggable Div </p> </div>'
$(data).appendTo($(this)).draggable();
```

It works fine.

My application heavily depends on mouse cursor type.
So, I change cursor every now and then programatically.

Now, I want that:

Draggable class should only be doing its work if the mouse cursor of a draggable element is default cursor.

How can I change this behavior without making changes in jQueryUI.js file if possible.

Comment: Don't know whether this is possible or not without changing the jQueryUI.js file but to achieve your goal you have to enable and disable draggables like myObj.draggable("disable") and myObj.draggable("enable")...... each and every place where you are changing cursor type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [start](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) event.

```
$("#data").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
     if ($(this).css('cursor') === 'auto') { //replace "auto"
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

I have created a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xahue7oj/23/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's great to hear. Glad I could help :)